# .net datagridview cell transparent back color

Tags: .net, datagridview, c++-cli, backcolor

I have a 4x4 datagridview. Every cell has a special backcolor.

So I want the selected cell background to be transparent. I googled about it, but I dont find a valid solution. when I set the selection color to transparent, the (default)first selected cell(0,0) back color is seemed white, when the user changed the selected cell, transparent back color property works fine.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ezineasp.net/category/ASP-Net-C-Sharp-GridView-Control.aspx

please review above site may be help you.